# Post-processing with inculude javascript

Tags: google-bigquery, dataform

I want to do Alter Tables as post-processing in an inculude javascript for DataForm, but only Operate is supported. sqlx files have a PostOps method, but I want to do it in an inculude js, i.e. as a common process, I would like to execute the post-processingalter table as a common process.
The following code is not working due to an executable processing problem.

```
operate(fqdnTableName+" add pk").queries(  c=>
    `ALTER TABLE ${fqdnTableName} ADD PRIMARY KEY (${pk}) NOT ENFORCED;`
);
```